# Cypress select does not have value

Tags: javascript, cypress

I´m writing a Cypress test in which I want to confirm that a certain value is not shown.
I want to check that my select element does not have an option with a certain value.

An example:

```html
<select>
 <option>A</option>
 <option>B</option>
</select>
```

So now I want to check that there isn´t an option with value "C"

```js
cy.get('select') // <-- here I want to verify that option "C" doesn´t exist
```

Can someone help me evaluate this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
cy.get('select option:contains(C)').should('not.exist')
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1. For a specific position, you can check like this:

```js
cy.get('select option').eq(0).should('not.have.text', 'C')
```

2. You can also loop over all the `Options` and check that 'C' is not present:

```js
cy.get('select option').each(($ele) => {
  expect($ele).to.not.have.text('C')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers solve the original question, where you're searching by tag name. But best practice is to use some test id as an identifier instead:

```
<select data-testid="mySelect">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
```

Since it may not be obvious to everyone, you can simply replace `select` with the identifier:

```
cy.get(`[data-testid="mySelect"] option`)
  .should("have.length", 2)
  .and("include.text", "A")
  .and("include.text", "B")
```

Or you can find the `select` element first and then use `cy.find` to find the `option`s within it:

```
cy.get(`[data-testid="mySelect"]`)
  .find("option")
  .should("have.length", 2)
  .and("include.text", "A")
  .and("include.text", "B")
```

(Note that I'm using `"include.text"` here, which only works if you know your options will be distinct. If you had a third option `<option>AB</option>` you'd want to use `cy.each` to cycle through each one individually or `eq(n).should("have.text")` to grab a specific option by index.)